# Deleting polygons within polygons using Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, delete, arcgis-10.8

I have smaller polygons -within bigger polygons-, and they supposed to by "holes" in the bigger ones. Based on the answers of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12880/finding-polygons-within-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop) I know how to identify them, and also how to get rid of the small polygons filling up the holes.

I also managed to make a model based on this. My problem is that it only works if the source feature classes are added to the table of contents and I put them in the model manually. Is there an other way to do this process as the "inside" part of a way bigger model?

Here is my model for easier visualization of my problem:

[image]

- The `source` and the `source copy` are identical
- `Select Layer By Location`: I select the features that are **comletely within** the other features, which results the "inner rings" of the polygons.
- `Select Layer By Location(2)`: I simply switch the selection, so I can remove the unnecessary features, which happens in `Delete Features`.
- `Erase`: I use the previous results as the **erase feature** with the copy of the original feature class as the **input feature**.

Now this works perfectly as I said, but only if the `source` and `source copy` are already added to the Table Of Contents, and only if I set them in the model manually every time.

Is there a way to do the same process within a model, with feature classes as the results of some other tools?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click `source` & `source_copy` and choose `Model Parameter`. This will enable other scripts/models to feed directly into this model.

The source will need to be a feature layer, not a feature class. You would need to run a feature class through the `Make Feature Layer` tool first.